# Shortcode displays always first. Once again

Tags: widgets, shortcode

OK, I've had a problem with echoes in my last shortcodem, but everything works fine now.

But I have another one:

```
function myWidget_shortcode( $atts ) {
        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'title' => 'My Widget',
        'value' => '5',
        ), $atts ) );

        return the_widget(myWidget,'title='.$title.'&value='.$value);
}

add_shortcode('myWidget', 'myWidget_shortcode');
```

Can you tell me wy this shortcode always displays first on pages? There's no echo etc., all the data is being returned...

[found the answer - edit]

**This resolves the problem:**

```
ob_start();    
the_widget(popularPosts,'title='.$title.'&number='.$number);
return ob_get_clean();
```

Anyways I don't understand why it's always first in this case. Because the_widget is a function itself and echoes something? :>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, look at the `widget()` method in your `MyWidget` class. Does it echo? Most likely it does, because that's how widgets are normally written. In fact, I'd be surprised to see a widget that didn't echo output in its `widget()` method.

And when you call `the_widget()`, it fetches an instance of the widget you ask for, and calls `$widget_obj->widget($args, $instance);`. So it echos, and doesn't return anything.